# Set height of li without "position: absolute"

Tags: html, css, height, html-lists, listitem

I want to make a menu with li elements that have a background, so I wanted to set the `height` and `width`, but I can't do that. I tried `position: absolute;`, but when I do that, the list items go on top of each other.

Is there a way to change the height/width without `position: absolute;`?

I never ran into this problem before and I can't figure out what it is, I hope you can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: display: block; float: left; try that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to adjust the `line-height`  or use `display: block` togheter with `width` and `height`:

```
<ul class="one">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>

<ul class="two">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>

.one li {
    line-height: 2em;
    background-color: green;
}

.two li {
    display: block;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PJvq4/

Answer (score 1):

The LI element is by default a *display:list-item*, which ignores height.
Height and width are css properties valid for display block and inline-block or floated elements.

in your case if you want a vertical list with elements with a fixed height go for *display:block* as it implies line-break.

hoping that helps

Comment: thanks you, always good to know why something fails instead of only how it would work.